# How do I add a line between words/numbers from a String Array in Java?

Tags: java

Confusing title, but all I want to know is how do I break up a long line of words, or in this case numbers.

I am jotting down zip codes of a town/city that a user types in. Some towns/cities have a lot of zip codes and the output is quite long.

I want to break up these lines at every 100 characters so they're easier to read.

```
I would like output to look like this: 

You asked me to search for place: Chicago, Il


Chicago, Il has zip codes: [60601, 60602, 60603, 60604, 60605, 60606, 
60607, 60608, 60609, 60610, 60611, 60612, 60613, 60614, 60615, 60616, 
60617, 60618, 60619, 60620, 60621, 60622, 60623, 60624, 60625, 60626, 
60628, 60629, 60630, 60631, 60632, 60633, 60634, 60636, 60637, 60638, 
60639, 60640, 60641, 60643, 60644, 60645, 60646, 60647, 60649, 60651, 
60652, 60653, 60654, 60655, 60656, 60657, 60659, 60660, 60661, 60663, 
60664, 60665, 60667, 60668, 60669, 60670, 60671, 60672, 60673, 60674, 
60675, 60677, 60678, 60679, 60680, 60681, 60683, 60684, 60685, 60687,  
60690, 60691, 60693, 60694, 60697, 60699, 60701]

^^^ My current output is that, but all in one line. ^^^
```

I want to know how I can fix it so it looks like that. Here is my current code at the moment.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
* In this class, I will obtain two private variables that are a type 
String and ArrayList.
 * The String will be the location that the user types in and the zip 
code will be the zip codes
 * that exist within that town/city.
 */
public class Place
{
 private ArrayList<String> zipCodes;
 private String location;

 /**
  * In this method, we find the file in which we will retrieve this 
  data. We put it in a Scanner and
  * put each line in an ArrayList that is ZipCodes.
  * @throws FileNotFoundException if the file doesn't exist.
  */
 public Place() throws FileNotFoundException
 {

    File zipsFile = new File("/Users/adanvivero/IdeaProjects/assignment 
 6/zips.txt");
    zipCodes = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner coordinates = new Scanner(zipsFile);

    while(coordinates.hasNextLine())
    {
        String lineScan = coordinates.nextLine();
            zipCodes.add(lineScan);
    }
 }

/**
 * In this method, we print out the zip code of the town/city in which 
the user typed in.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException We use this since we used a file in 
the String method, setZipCode
  * down below.
  */
 public void addPlace() throws FileNotFoundException
 {
    String theSummary = location + " has zip codes: " + setZipCodes();
    if(theSummary.length() > 100)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(theSummary);
    }

 }

 /**
 * In this method, we retrieve the zip code of the city/town. I have 
two ArrayList since I don't need
 * to get the coordinates of the file, but rather only the name of the 
town and the zip code of it. Therefore,
 * I add the zip codes into one of the ArrayList, which in this 
instance happen to be our private one, and
 * the name of the location in another Arraylist.
 * @return We return a String that will be the zipCodes which is in an 
Array, but converted as a String.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException We retrieve the file in which these 
will come out in. If the file doesn't exist,
 * we throw a FileNotFoundException.
 */
public String setZipCodes() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File zipsFile = new File("/Users/adanvivero/IdeaProjects/assignment 
6/zips.txt");
    //ArrayList<String> zips = new ArrayList<String>();
    zipCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner console = new Scanner(zipsFile);

    while(console.hasNextLine())
    {
        String z = console.nextLine();
        String [] zip = z.split("\t");
        String [] code = z.split("\t");
        if(location.equalsIgnoreCase(code[3]))
        {
            zipCodes.add(zip[0]);
            codes.add(code[3]);
        }
    }
    String theSummary = zipCodes.toString();
    for(int i = 0; i <= theSummary.length()-1; i++)
    {
        while(theSummary.charAt(i) == 100)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
        return zipCodes.toString();
 }

/**
 * In this String method, we as the user to type in a place and we 
return the place the user typed in so other
 * methods can use it.
 * @return it returns the String of the location the user types in.
 */
public String getLocation()
{
    Scanner wuddup = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("You asked me to search for place: ");
    location = wuddup.nextLine();
    return location;
}
}
```

So I believe to solve my problem is under the setZipCode() method or on my addPlace() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addPlace() do this:

```
 String theSummary = location + " has zip codes: " + setZipCodes();
 String theNewSummary = "";
 for(int i = 0; i < theSummary.length()-1; i = i+100){
          if(i+99 < theSummary.length()-1)
          theNewSummary += theSummary.substring(i, i+99)+"\r\n";
          else
           theNewSummary += theSummary.substring(i, theSummary.length()-1);

 }
 System.out.print(theNewSummary );
```

In order to display 10 zipcodes per line:

```
  String theSummary = location + " has zip codes: \r\n";
  String[] zipCodes = setZipCodes().split(" ");
  for(int i = 0; i < zipCodes.length; i++){
       theSummary += " "+zipCodes[i];
       if(i%10 == 0 && i !=0)
           theSummary +="\r\n"
  }
  System.out.print(theSummary );
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 600, end 699, length 608
 at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3107)
 at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1873)
 at places.Place.addPlace(Place.java:63)
 at places.PlaceFinder.main(PlaceFinder.java:14)

Comment: It works, but now I want to make it so it doesn't break up any of the zip codes. I want the zip codes to finish together and then start a new line.

Comment: ok, i will edit my post to do that, but to make things easier, I am going to make it so there are 10 zip codes per line.  give me a minute

Comment: I appreciate it, if possible, I want to try to keep each line under 100 characters. I'll tweak if I have to, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: I edited the post.  You can figure out how many zip codes per line you need and simply modify the 10 in  i%10 to how many every zipcodes you want to have per line.

Comment: Alright, this answers everything I need it to. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From addPlace() you can call this method to format the output.

The advantages of this method are that it can:-

1. Split the string in any length
2. Doesn't break the line in the middle of the zip code.

Working code :-

```
/**
 * Format a String to specific line length.
 * @param summary : Input string
 * @param maxLineLength Max line length.
 * @param delim String delimeter to be used for breaking the string like space or comma
 * @return the formated sting
 */
public static String formatSummary(String summary, int maxLineLength, String delim) {
    //convert long string to array of word by delim and discard empty string.
    List<String> summarySplitByDelim = Arrays.stream(summary.split(delim)).filter(a->a.length() > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    StringBuilder formattedSummary = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();
    for (String currentWord : summarySplitByDelim) {
        // Keep on adding word by word to currentline
        currentLine.append(currentWord.trim()).append(delim);
        //if current line execeed our line length, dump everything to formatedSummary and reset currentline
        if(currentLine.length() > maxLineLength){
            formattedSummary.append(currentLine).append(newLine);
            currentLine = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }
    //Add the last line if not added because the loop exited.
    if(currentLine.length() > 0){
        formattedSummary.append(currentLine).append(newLine);
    }
    return formattedSummary.toString();
}
```

**Calling the method like `formatSummary(data, 80, " ");` will produce the output**

`Chicago, Il has zip codes: [60601, 60602, 60603, 60604, 60605, 60606, 60607, 60608, 
60609, 60610, 60611, 60612, 60613, 60614, 60615, 60616, 60617, 60618, 60619, 60620, 
60621, 60622, 60623, 60624, 60625, 60626, 60628, 60629, 60630, 60631, 60632, 60633, 
60634, 60636, 60637, 60638, 60639, 60640, 60641, 60643, 60644, 60645, 60646, 60647, 
60649, 60651, 60652, 60653, 60654, 60655, 60656, 60657, 60659, 60660, 60661, 60663, 
60664, 60665, 60667, 60668, 60669, 60670, 60671, 60672, 60673, 60674, 60675, 60677, 
60678, 60679, 60680, 60681, 60683, 60684, 60685, 60687, 60690, 60691, 60693, 60694, 
60697, 60699, 60701]`